# Does EQU in 68K save anything in memory?

Tags: 68000

I'm doing an assignment where I have to draw a memory map and it says "C  EQU  4", I know EQU assigns the value 4 to C but what does this actually put into memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EQU doesn't put anything in memory. It simply assigns a textual identifier to a number (assigns a numeric constant to a symbolic constant).

If you know C, EQU is pretty close to what `#define` does.